# Virtual function, why is the base class function called here?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

Can someone please help me on what I'm doing wrong ? Always the base class pointer is called !  I'm trying to make a Map of custom class objects.  Tried both through find and indexing directly as well, but same result !

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Map>
#include <algorithm>

class Command
{
public:
    virtual int execute(std::string *args) { std::cout << "Base called ! ERROR!\n"; return -1; }
};

class ShowNames : public Command
{
public:
    int execute(std::string names)
    {
        std::cout << names;
        return 0;
    }
};

class ShowNos : public Command
{
public:
    int execute(std::string Nos)
    {
        std::cout << Nos;
        return 0;
    }
};

typedef std::map<std::string, Command*> CmdList;

CmdList buildMaps()
{
    CmdList c1;
    ShowNames s1;
    ShowNos   n1;

    c1["names"] = new ShowNames();
    c1["nos"] = new ShowNos();

    //c1.find("names")

    return c1;
}

void testCommandList()
{
    CmdList commands;
    Command *c1;
    commands = buildMaps();

    std::string cmd,args;
    std::cout << "Enter your command: ";
    std::cin >> cmd;
    std::cout << "Enter args for the command: ";
    std::cin >> args;

     auto it = commands.find(cmd);
     if (it != commands.end())
     {
         it->second->execute(&args);
     }
     else
     {
         std::cout << "Command not found, try again\n";
     }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

You're not overriding the base function in the derived classes, you're declaring new functions. Compare the function types:

```
int   Command::execute(std::string *args)
int ShowNames::execute(std::string  names)
int   ShowNos::execute(std::string  Nos)
```

(Aligned to make it more obvious)

To override a base-class function, you must match the signature exactly (except for a covariant return type, if needed). So change the signatures to be the same. Which one is correct depends on your problem domain, of course.

This is why C++11 introduced they reserved word `override` which you can put on a virtual function which you intend to override a base-class function. It will then result in a compilation error if that's not the case. If you have access to C++11, you should *always* use it when you mean it, like this:

```
class ShowNames : public Command
{
public:
    int execute(std::string names) override
    {
        std::cout << names;
        return 0;
    }
};
```

This would immediately tell you that it does not override any base class functions, and you would be in a much better position to start investigating why.

Answer (score 4):

You never actually overwrite your base class method.

```
virtual int execute(std::string *args)
```

This is the signature. You need to stick to it, not change it.